# Android GridView Repeating Images

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

Im having a little problem with gridview the iamges shows normally but when i scroll down then i scroll up the images positions change or repeat i dont know why iam little bit confused, i use over 50 to 100 images but now only 19 images i was testing how it will be so i got that problem and it wont stick on its position .
Thanks .

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;


public Integer[] images = {
        R.drawable.f_alicate,R.drawable.f_arcoajustable,
        R.drawable.f_bateria,R.drawable.f_bisagra,
        R.drawable.f_bisagra2,R.drawable.f_cadena_galvanizada,
        R.drawable.f_canilla_bronze ,R.drawable.f_canilla_con_palanca,
        R.drawable.f_casco_rojo,R.drawable.f_casco_rojo2,
        R.drawable.f_cerraduracajon,R.drawable.f_cerradura_para_cajon2,
        R.drawable.f_conexion_cromado,R.drawable.f_cotra_candena,
        R.drawable.f_cuchara_albanil,R.drawable.f_cutter,
        R.drawable.f_cutter2,R.drawable.f_disco,
        R.drawable.f_corta_hiero};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView = null ;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(images[position]);

            //create new ImageView if it is not present and populate it with some image
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            //re-use ImageView that already exists in memory
        }
    return imageView;
}


class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(ImageAdapter.this.context.getResources(), data, 450, 450);
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(450, 450));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

}

Comment: Since it looks like you're dispatching async requests to grab images, and from what I'm seeing in the code above you're not canceling the requests when a view is recycled this could be causing the issue you're seeing.  However, since some of the code is //seudo code, it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item_layout, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = (View) convertView;
    }
    TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
    text.setText(mTextIds[position]);
    ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    image.setImageDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In getView(), when re-use ImageView that already exists you still need to set the image of that view.
What you do actually is to set the image when it is a new ImageView only.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**
*main fragment*

```
public class Fragment_Main_Dashboard extends Fragment {
GridView dashbord_icon;


List<ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list> dashbord_list1 = getAllItemObject();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashbord_alert_list, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().setTitle("Dashboard");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Service_for_login_check.class);
    getActivity().startService(intent);

    dashbord_icon = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_icon);


    Custom_Adapter_Dashboard_grid adapter1 = new Custom_Adapter_Dashboard_grid(getActivity(), dashbord_list1);
    dashbord_icon.setAdapter(adapter1);


    dashbord_icon.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object o = dashbord_icon.getItemAtPosition(position);


            if (position == 0) {
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Main_Advance_tracking();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.texeting_fram, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Main_Vehicle_Status();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.texeting_fram, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } else if (position == 2) {
                Intent All_veickle = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Drawer_Dashboard.class);
                Boolean key = true;
                All_veickle.putExtra("total_veickle", key);

                startActivity(All_veickle);
                getActivity().finish();

            } else if (position == 3) {


                Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Main_Alerts();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.texeting_fram, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


            } else if (position == 4) {
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Main_VEHICLE_Setting();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.texeting_fram, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            } else {
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Main_Support();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.texeting_fram, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


            }


        }


    });


    return view;
}


private List<ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list> getAllItemObject() {
    List<ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list(R.drawable.dashbord_icon1, "ADVANCE TRACKING", 0));
    items.add(new ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list(R.drawable.dashbord_icon2, "VEHICLE STATUS", 0));

    items.add(new ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list(R.drawable.dashbord_icon4, "TOTAL VEHICLES", 0));
    items.add(new ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list(R.drawable.dashbord_icon3, "ALERTS", 0));
    items.add(new ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list(R.drawable.dashbord_icon5, "VEHICLE SETTINGS", 0));
    items.add(new ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list(R.drawable.dashbord_icon6, "SUPPORT", 0));


    return items;
}

//****************this is for inflatting nodification count funtionality
public Drawable buildCounterDrawable(int count, int backgroundImageId, Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_counter_menuitem_layout, null);
    view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

    if (count == 0 || count >= 100) {
        View counterTextPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.counterValuePanel);
        counterTextPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        textView.setText("" + count);
    }

    view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
        Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menu.clear();

    MenuItem item =
            menu.add(Menu.FIRST, R.id.dashboard_nodifycation, 3, "NODIFICATION");
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    menu.add(Menu.FIRST, R.id.System_log, 4, "LOGOUT");

    Database_for_GCM_data dbHelper = null;
    dbHelper = new Database_for_GCM_data(getActivity());
    int unread_count = Integer.parseInt(dbHelper.getUnreadCount());
    // calling function for nodification inflater
    item.setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(unread_count, R.drawable.white_nodification, getActivity()));


}
```

}

*fragment xml layout*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"></GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

*custom adapter*

```
public class Custom_Adapter_Dashboard_grid extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater layoutinflater;
private List<ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list> listStorage;
private Context context;

public Custom_Adapter_Dashboard_grid(Context context, List<ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list> customizedListView) {
    this.context = context;
    try {


        layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listStorage = customizedListView;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return listStorage.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_adapter_dashbord_grid_list, parent, false);
        listViewHolder.screenShot = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);

        listViewHolder.musicName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_name);


        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    listViewHolder.screenShot.setImageResource(listStorage.get(position).getimage());
    listViewHolder.musicName.setText(listStorage.get(position).geticonName());


    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView screenShot;
    TextView musicName;

}
```

}
*custom adapter layout*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="sample"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*item obj*

```
public class ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list {

private int dashbord;
private String iconname1;
String unread;


public ItemObj_for_Dashbord_list(int screenShot, String iconname, int unreadcound) {
    dashbord = screenShot;
    iconname1 = iconname;
    unread = String.valueOf(unreadcound);

}

public int getimage() {
    return dashbord;
}

public String geticonName() {
    return iconname1;
}

public String getunreadcount() {
    return unread;
}
```

}